# Cann't check a file extension in php

Tags: php, file-extension, pathinfo

The case statement in php here to check a mime type is working fine.

```
$mimetype = mime_content_type($path);
switch ($mimetype) {

    case "video/mp4":
    case "video/mov":
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

However, the case statement in php here to check a file extention is not, and in this case pathinfo($path) is not extracting a filename such as VID_2_134.mp4. I guess the way I used pathinfo($path) is not correct, but I don't know the correct way to use it. If I replace pathinfo($path) with VID_2_134.mp4 below the case statement starts to work with the way I expected.

```
$filepath = pathinfo($path);
$extension = $filepath['extension'];
switch ($extension) {

     case "mp4":
     case "mov":
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

*$path is a file path from the local drive of pc or smartphone where the file exist.
```

Can anyone please help me out?

Comment: So what does `$filepath` contain? It should be an associative array  Can you dump it?

Comment: Was about to suggest `var_dump($path);` and `var_dump($filepath);`

Comment: I'm almost sure there's a special character (a newline at the end?) that prevents pathinfo() from working correctly.

Comment: arkascha, thanks. It says array(2) { ["basename"]=> string(0) "" ["filename"]=> string(0) "" }

Comment: Cid, string(14) "/tmp/phpoV3m9a" array(3) { ["dirname"]=> string(4) "/tmp" ["basename"]=> string(9) "phpoV3m9a" ["filename"]=> string(9) "phpoV3m9a" }

Comment: Looks like that's a file without extension or you forgot to add the file.

Comment: I do see the extension of the file when I choose it for uploading.

Comment: It is a temporary upload. Upload it, then get the extension when it is a standard file.

Comment: Thank you all. Your insights and advises helped me a lot. Since a file in $path does not contain an extension in this particular case which I did not realize  I managed to check a file extension by changing the root from $path to temp folder. I really appreciate your supports.